# Getting chrome to go full screen, programmatically

Tags: html, google-chrome

When I view the impress.js website in chrome on iOS, the tab bar slides up and disappears. How do I do that?

Note: doesn't happen in safari on iOS.

Answer (score 4):

A simple Google search would suffice for this question.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/10/Let-Your-Content-Do-the-Talking-Fullscreen-API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode
http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen

All are excellent resources (and the top three Google links!).

Essentially, there's a new API which allows JS to request fullscreen access. That's about it.